# how can I use scm username and password in own maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

My release command

```
mvn -B -f pom.xml -DdevelopmentVersion=2.5-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=2.4 -Dusername=tom -Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform -Dpassword=*********
```

how can I use scm username and password in own maven plugin?

Comment: This is really unclear. Are you writing your own maven plugin? Could you post your POM?

Comment: May be I can read it from release.properties file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i correctly understand you need to do [something like this](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html):

```
mvn -B -DdevelopmentVersion=2.5-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=2.4 \
 -Darguments='-Dusername=XXX -Dpassword=WhatEver'
```

The tricky parts is `-Darguments='-Dusername=XXX -Dpassword=WhatEver'` this is needed cause the release plugin forks an instance of Maven which really is doing the work and that's the reason the information like username, password are not passed to the forked instance of Maven.